# C# Create Web API & Add API Key Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, api-key

I am trying to add API Key authentication to the Web API I am building however when I test it on Postman, it doesn't seem to be picking up the authentication requirement. I am using an Attribute called 'APIKeyAuthAttribute' like so;

```
    [AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class APIKeyAuthAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {

        private const string ApiKeyHeaderName = "MyApiKey";
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {

            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(ApiKeyHeaderName, out var potentialAPIKey))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Api Key was not provided."
                };
                return;
            }

            var appSettings = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(ApiKeyHeaderName);

            if (!apiKey.Equals(potentialAPIKey))
              {
                context.Result = new ContentResult
                {
                    StatusCode = 401,
                    Content = "Unauthorized Client."
                };
                return;
            }

            await next();
          
        }
    }
```

I created an appsettings.json file which looks like this;

```
{

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyApiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

In my main Controller which does the heavy lifting and retrieves a=the data for the Get request, I added the reference to the Attribute;

```
    [ApiController]
    [APIKeyAuth]
    public class MyStudentController : ApiController
    {......
```

I am at a loss as to how/why this isn't working. When I start the API and make a Get request on Postman, I get a Status 200 OK response even when I declare the 'MyApiKey' key and purposely provide an incorrect value in the Header. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try registering it like [ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiKeyAuth))] because its a async filter.

Comment: @AliK thank you for the reply - let me give that a try and see if it works. Bear with...

Comment: @AliK unfortunately, that didn't do anything either...*sigh*

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the filter to make sure the values are what you expect.?